# Return data from postrgre query in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I proprely return the data I want from a postgre query ?

```js
function getTableName() {
    let queryTableName = `SELECT * FROM admin.information_schema.tables;`;
    let response;

    client.query(queryTableName).then(res => {
        let names = Array();
        for (let i = 0; i < res.rowCount; i++) {
            names.push(res.rows[i]['table_name']);
        }
        response = names;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code returns the response *synchronously*, before the query result has arrived from the database *asynchronously*. Therefore what you return is still undefined.

You must either convert `getTableName` into an [asynchronous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), or implement an express middleware, which is by nature asynchronous:

```js
app.get("/path", function(req, res, next) {
  let queryTableName = `SELECT * FROM admin.information_schema.tables;`;
  client.query(queryTableName).then(resp => {
    let names = Array();
    for (let i = 0; i < resp.rowCount; i++) {
      names.push(resp.rows[i]['table_name']);
    }
    res.json(names);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    next(err);
  });
});
```